# Resize2fs shrink operation leaves free space in filesystem?

Tags: resize2fs

I'm trying to shrink a filesystem image down to the smallest possible size. I'm okay with resize2fs leaving reserved filesystem blocks in place, but it's leaving about 400Mb of free space in the filesystem after the shrink operation.

These are the steps I'm performing:

```
aj@pop-os:~/disk_images$ sudo losetup -fP --show mcard.img 
/dev/loop0

aj@pop-os:~/disk_images$ sudo zerofree -v /dev/loop0p1
112082/2671282/3665210

aj@pop-os:~/disk_images$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/loop0p1
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/loop0p1: 191007/917504 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 993928/3665210 blocks

aj@pop-os:~/disk_images$ sudo resize2fs -Mp /dev/loop0p1
resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/loop0p1 to 1115084 (4k) blocks.
Begin pass 2 (max = 3444)
Relocating blocks             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Begin pass 3 (max = 112)
Scanning inode table          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
The filesystem on /dev/loop0p1 is now 1115084 (4k) blocks long.
```

Everything seems to work fine and it does shrink the filesystem down from 16Gb to 4.1Gb. However, it does leave free space on the filesystem:

```
aj@pop-os:~/disk_images$ sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 xmnt/
aj@pop-os:~/disk_images$ df -h xmnt/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0p1    4.1G  3.5G  434M  90% /home/aj/disk_images/xmnt

aj@pop-os:~/disk_images$ sudo umount xmnt/
aj@pop-os:~/disk_images$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/loop0p1
(Output shortened for readability)
Block count:              1115084
Reserved block count:     47712
Free blocks:              162785
Block size:               4096
```

As you can see, after shrinking the filesystem, both the `df` utility and `dumpe2fs` show free space remaining in the filesystem image.

Why is this and how can I get resize2fs to actually reduce the filesystem size such that there is no free space aside from the reserved blocks?